# Jekyll not setting variable properly in Liquid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have been trying to adopt a single set of column styles that are used across my website, but the Liquid assign tag isn't working properly.

I only have one template so far, called default.html:

```
---

---

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include header.html %}
  <body>
    {% include navbar.html %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% assign __align__col = col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 %}
            <p>Using align {{ __align__col }}</p>
            <div class="{{ __align__col }}">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  {% if page.title %}
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h3 class="panel-title">{{ page.title }}</h3>
                    </div>
                  {% endif %}
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    {{ content }}
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="{{ __align__col }}">
                {% include footer.html %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem resides in the `{% assign __align__col = col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 %}` line, it doesn't seem to set the `__align__col` variable. I looked at the source, and it doesn't show up in the class attribute or in the `<p>` tag.

I have Bootstrap running to do the UI stuff, and it's hosted over [here](https://github.com/TechShroom/TechShroom.github.io) at GitHub Pages. Actual website is [here](http://techshroom.github.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misunderstood the assign tag. It probably needs to be a string in there, like `{% assign __align__col = "col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" %}`. I'm not using this anyways, so this is probably the best answer I have for this.